# What is the meaning of -D commandline options when executing java

Tags: java, command-line, jvm

I find myself running java code from jars or classes and am given instructions to set commandline flags like -Dfoo=bar

When debugging or attempting to run some lightly documented feature I am having trouble understanding how the values are actually included in the running code.

I look at the source, and it is unclear how the data set with something like -Dfoo=bar is actually ingested.

The core question I have is what does the -D stand for, and how should it be expected to be visible in source code?

Comment: Please refer to [the official documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html#BABDJJFI).

Comment: This option sets system properties which are available anywhere in code.

Answer (score 1):

From `java -help`:

> -D<name>=<value>
>   
>     set a system property

From [the `java` tool documentation page](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/tools/java.htm#JSWOR624):

> -D*property*=*value*
>   
> Sets a system property value. The *property* variable is a string with no spaces that represents the name of the property. The *value* variable is a string that represents the value of the property. If *value* is a string with spaces, then enclose it in quotation marks (for example `-Dfoo="foo bar"`)

The "D" could be thought of as "define." You access values set in this way via [`System.getProperty(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getProperty(java.lang.String)), [`System.getProperty(String,String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getProperty(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)), or [`System.getProperties()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getProperties()).